# How do I get the value of a drop down menu from a pdf file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, itext

I am ingesting a PDF file that has been filled out however, I am unable to retrieve the export value from a drop down menu that is present in the form.

I am using Visual Studios to test and visualize the values that are filled out in the form, and the drop down menu has been the only issue that I have when trying to retrieve its' value.

```
AcroFields.Item items = resField.GetFieldItem(fieldNameInXFADictionary);
PdfDictionary valueDict = items.GetValue(0);
PdfName curVal = valueDict.GetAsName(PdfName.AS);

if (curVal != null)
{
    String result = curVal.ToString();

    if (result == "/1")
    {
        result = "YES";
    }
    else if (result == "/Off" || result == "/OFF")
    {
        result = "NO";
    }
    else if (result == "/2")
    {
        result = "YES";
    }
    count = 1;
    return result;
}
else if(curVal == null)
{
    return resField.Fields.Values.ToString();
}
```

When testing, the field should not be `null`, however, when it is converted into `PdfName` `curVal`, it is determined as `null` which does not make much sense to me. 
Therefore, it enters the else statement which returns "System.util.collections.LinkedDictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields+Item"

The value that is in the drop down menu is "United States".

Comment: No answer to your question yet, I need more time to do that. But you already `return result` before you enter your second `if`, so that is effectively dead code.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse sorry about that, I edited out the first "return result" out. I used the return result to test whether or not the field value was returning null or not null. And it does return a "Null" value therefore it moves on to the "else if" statement.

Comment: Your last `else` is redundant, however, if you invert your first `if`, then you have a Guard Clause. https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Comment: And I believe that C# is also capable of doing a `switch` on strings, no? Make it easy for yourself, use `curVal.ToString().ToUpper()`.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse so the switch on strings is not what I am looking for. I am looking for the output value, "United States", which was selected in a drop down menu in a pdf file. However, when reading the pdf file in Visual Studio, it is outputting that value as null.